# What does "standard that X builds to" mean?

Tags: meaning

> 'There is a standard that university builds to.'

Does it mean that there is a document where rules how to build an university are written?

Comment: Where did you see this phrase used?

Comment: It is an article in "Construction Today"

Answer (score 2):

A *standard* isn't necessary to be a document. [It just means](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/standard?q=standard) *an idea or thing used as a measure, norm, or model in comparative evaluations*. According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technical_standard), there are basically two types of standards.

> A **technical standard** is an established norm or requirement in regard
>   to technical systems. It is usually a formal document that establishes
>   uniform engineering or technical criteria, methods, processes and
>   practices. In contrast, a custom, convention, company product,
>   corporate standard, etc. that becomes generally accepted and dominant
>   is often called a **de facto standard**.

So if by *standard* you are talking about *technical standard*, then you are half correct: there is a document. But instead of saying "*a document where rules are written*", a more technical description would be "*a formal document that establishes uniform engineering or technical criteria, methods, processes and practices*".

Answer (score 1):

No. It does not refer to building the university. (Notice that "university" is the subject of the sentence, not the object.) Nor does it mean something physical. It refers to the academic and intellectual intentions of the institution. "Building to" means "working toward," and the standard it is working toward is one of two things: either the level of academic achievement it expects its students to reach, or the level of quality, recognition, or respect, to which the university itself aspires. (These are very closely connected, and may even be perceived as different ways of stating the same thing.)

This use of "standard," by the way, is not the adjective meaning "usual or typical." When we say "a standard" it becomes a noun meaning "a flag" -- in this case, a flag marking a level of attainment (in other words, a goal to be achieved).

Comment: Thank you! To making sure, may I say in other words, that "there is an ideal that university wants to achieve"?

Comment: Yes, that's very close to the same thing. Also note: In American English, "university" without "the" is not used much. We say "the university" to refer to a specific university, such as Harvard. In British English, "university" is used as a noun meaning a particular level of education, as in the sentence, "University will be good for your mental development." The same sentence in the U.S. would be said thus: "College will be good for your mental development." (In the U.S., we say it this way even if the person will be attending an actual university and not merely a single isolated college.)